# How to update LabelFrame title (Tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a novice and working with Tkinter for the first time. My project is an "I Spy" book which moves picture to picture utilizing buttons. I like the look of the LabelFrame widget and want to use the title for the text that corresponds with each image. I am able to achieve the images updating correctly but the title remains the same. I have tried config, forgetting and then rebuilding the frame, and I think something else which I can't recall and none of that has worked. I have searched online, reviewed Stack Overflow similar questions--which are very few and lead me to believe that this cannot be done. Thank you for your assistance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Button
from tkinter import Label
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image

root = Tk()
root.title('')
root.attributes('-toolwindow', True)
root.geometry('620x660+100+0')


img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('spy_images/rainbow.jpg'))
img4 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('spy_images/pods.jpg'))
img5 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('spy_images/lion.jpg'))
img6 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('spy_images/bike.jpg'))
img7 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('spy_images/binary.jpg'))

image_list = [img2, img4, img5, img6, img7]

text2 = 'A rainbow, not in the sky!'
text4 = 'Dangly, weird seed pods.'
text5 = 'A stoney grin.'
text6 = 'A lane just for bikes.'
text7 = 'A different way to count.'

text_list = [text2, text4, text5, text6, text7]

make_frame = LabelFrame(root, text='A rainbow, not in the sky!', width=100, height=100,
                        font=('Arial', 14, 'bold'), fg='red', bd=10)
make_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=5)
img_filename = 'spy_images/rainbow.jpg'
PIL_image = Image.open(img_filename)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL_image)
in_frame = Label(make_frame, image=img)
in_frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)


def forward(image_num, text_num):
    global make_frame
    global in_frame
    global button_forward
    global button_back

    in_frame.grid_forget()

    in_frame = Label(image=image_list[image_num])
    button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', command=lambda:
                            forward(image_num+1, text_num+1))
    button_back = Button(root, text='<<', command=lambda:
                         back(image_num-1, text_num-1))

    if image_num == 7:
        button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', state=DISABLED)

    make_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=5)

    in_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)
    in_frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

    button_forward.grid(row=1, column=5)
    button_back.grid(row=1, column=1)
    button_back.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    button_back.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    button_back.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)


def back(image_num, text_num):
    global make_frame
    global in_frame
    global button_forward
    global button_back

    in_frame.grid_forget()

    in_frame = Label(image=image_list[image_num - 1])
    button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', command=lambda:
                            forward(image_num + 1, text_num + 1))
    button_back = Button(root, text='<<', command=lambda:
                         back(image_num - 1, text_num - 1))

    if image_num == 1:
        button_back = Button(root, text='<<', state=DISABLED)

    make_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=5)

    in_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)
    in_frame.grid(padx=10, pady=10)

    button_forward.grid(row=1, column=5)
    button_back.grid(row=1, column=1)
    button_back.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    button_back.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
    button_back.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)


button_back = Button(root, text='<<', command=back, state=DISABLED, bg='#d9d5d4',
                     font=('Arial', 14, 'bold'))
button_exit = Button(root, text='Cancel', command=root.quit, bg='#d9d5d4', font=('Arial', 12))
button_forward = Button(root, text='>>', command=lambda: forward(2, 2), bg='#d9d5d4', font=('Arial', 14, 'bold'))

button_back.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_exit.grid(row=1, column=3)
button_forward.grid(row=1, column=5)

button_back.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
button_back.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
button_back.grid_columnconfigure(4, weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I have tried config"_ - that is the correct solution. What  happened when you tried it.

Comment: @BryanOakley I obviously used it incorrectly, the frame disappeared after the initial image was generated and no text at all. `make_frame.configure(text=text_list[text_num])`

Comment: Also learning by exploring `config`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some questions about the exampel I'll try to answer you.

```
    import tkinter as tk
#you dont need this but if you want to cycle, wich is would be nice there you go
from itertools import cycle

#create a list with strings you like to display
li = ['A rainbow, not in the sky!','Dangly, weird seed pods.','A stoney grin.',
      'A lane just for bikes.','A different way to count.']
#here we create a cycle of that list
my_cycled_li = cycle(li)

#the change function
def change():
  #set var to next element in list
  var.set(next(my_cycled_li))
  #update the LabelFrame
  lf.configure(text=var.get())

root = tk.Tk()
#variable to change
var = tk.StringVar()
#there can be a default setting
var.set('default')
lf = tk.LabelFrame(root,text=var.get(),width=200,height=100,bg='red')
#you dont need this, this means the Frame size isnt the size of the widget it contains.
lf.pack_propagate(0)
lf.pack()
b = tk.Button(lf,text='change', command=change)
b.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

hoped it helps.

Comment: The `var` is not necessary.

Comment: I see how the code works @Atlas435, it requires a button. Just prior to posting my question I had thought I must need to use `StringVar` because this `make_frame.configure(text=text_list[text_num])` just couldn't be correct but I decided to check here to see if this functionality was possible before pursuing. I have learned a better way to use a list in this case. Thank you.

Comment: @thisLinda I prefer this method just because I'm abel to cycle through. Happy codeing!

Comment: Also note you can put the code of change() in your forward and backward function. You will not need a seperate Button.

Comment: I never would have thought of that. Something else I've learned, thank you.

Comment: @acw1668 I am now trying to extend my learning and make the code work without `var`.

Comment: @acw1668 I had a issue once I was changing a text multiple times. After changingthe text some times it showed me nothing. Since then I use everytime to change a string or int a Var() for. You may right, but I leave it this way.