# What is the function used to update frame image automatically in python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I asked this question before and the previous one linked to another question but it didn't solve the problem.

I have a number of images, which are updated frequently in a file.
The names of images are on the same pattern (e.g: `img1.jpg` , `img2.jpg` ...)

I am programming a GUI on python tkinter to start from the first image and automatically update after 30 second.
after many tries, I have no idea how to achieve that because `mainloop()`function freezes the GUI and the problem is that I need them in one GUI.

Here is the code I used to open and resize images:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

x=1
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        load = Image.open("./images/img%s.jpg"%x)
        load=load.resize((1350,800))
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(load)
        img = Label(self, image=render)
        img.image = render
        img.place(x=0, y=0)
        
root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("Tkinter window")
root.geometry("1350x800")
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to use `label.after(3000,function)` but no results came up so I deleted it from the code.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `load = Image.open("./images/img%s.jpg"%x)` x? what is x?

Comment: How do you achieve this "updated frequently" in your code?

Comment: You have to loop at some point in the code anyway.

Comment: @CoolCloud the images names are img1 img2 etc... so i am planning to open the next image by increasing x value every 30 second to show the image

Comment: Anyway x is not getting increased in the example you gave

Comment: @CoolCloud i know i need a solution for this case because it depends on a function and i tried a lot of functions without and benefits

Comment: Show us a single way you tried and we will fix it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didnt kept a reference. Anyway, maybe this will give you an idea of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62200353/13629335

Answer (score 1):

Too big for the comments, But this is a working version of your code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.x = 1 #assigning x to 1 to start with img1 
        self.load = Image.open(f"./images/img{self.x}.jpg").resize((1350,800),Image.ANTIALIAS) #loading first img
        self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load) #instantiating first img
        self.img = Label(self, image=self.render) #labelizing it
        self.img.image = self.render #keeping reference
        self.img.pack() #packing it because place(x=0,y=0) will lead to overwriting of image
        self.master.after(3000,self.update) #calling the function continoursly
    def update(self):
        self.x+=1 #increasing the x by 1 over each call to function
        if self.x < 9:
            self.load = Image.open(f"./images/img{self.x}.jpg").resize((1350,800),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load)
            self.img.config(image=self.render) #changing the image of label
            self.master.after(3000,self.update)

root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("Tkinter window")
root.geometry("1350x800")
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helped, do let me know if any errors or doubts.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot but this code works for only the first 2 images so i updated it and i will share it in a comment

Comment: @AliAltaher Actually, would appreciate if you accept my answer

Comment: `self.rep` is undefined in your second solution.  Also `self.master.after(3000, self.update)` is still be executed even though `self.x == 9` is true, is it what your solution wants?

Comment: @acw1668 what about now?

Comment: `self.rep` is still undefined.  Actually you don't need to call `after_cancel()`, just use `if self.x < 9: load the image and call after()`.

Comment: Either ways, its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my problem:

```
#from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
from tkinter import Frame,Label,BOTH,Tk
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.x = 1
        self.load = Image.open(f"./images/img{self.x}.jpg").resize((1350,800),Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load)
        self.img = Label(self, image=self.render)
        self.img.image = self.render
        self.img.pack()
        self.master.after(3000,self.update)
    def update(self):
        if self.x<len(os.listdir("./images/")):

            self.x+=1
            self.load = Image.open(f"./images/img{self.x}.jpg").resize((1350,800),Image.ANTIALIAS)
            self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.load)
            self.img.config(image=self.render)
            self.master.after(3000,self.update)

        else:
            self.x=1
            self.master.after(1,self.update)
root = Tk()
app = Window(root)
root.wm_title("Tkinter window")
root.geometry("1350x800")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `after(1, ...)` is somewhat dangerious. You're trying to call a function 1000 times per second which could starve the tkinter event loop.

Comment: @BryanOakley no friend it will call once to reset the images index to the first one

Comment: If `len(os.listdir("./images/"))` is 1 or 0, this code will attempt to run 1000 times per second.